# Sql server stored procedure and indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, if a stored procedure is created before indices is created, will the stored procedure use those indices after they have been created?

Comment: a simple answer: yes, it would :)

Comment: Slightly more complicated answer: probably it would :)

Comment: Stored procedures run on the table whether there are index's or not.

Comment: @dean why not put that as the answer, so that this question no longer appears in the "unanswered" queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes it would. Stored procedures can even exist before the tables that they use exist.

A longer answer means you need to know about execution plans and the plan cache that SQL Server keeps. When a procedure is run, the plan for it (which can include the indexes to use) is cached and kept for a period of time. So it's possible that the index will get used immediately or after the current execution plan has expired from the cache.

Take a look at [Execution plan basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/) for more info.